# RelativeLayout not positioning view on center horizontal when setting X Factor .5

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on `RelativeLayout`, I have three `BoxView`. `boxview3` I want to get after `boxview2` using `Type=RelativeToView`.

`boxview3`'s `XConstraint` I am setting `.5` still `boxview3` displaying at top left why? How can I get `boxview3` just after `boxview2`?

```
<RelativeLayout>
<BoxView x:Name="boxview1" BackgroundColor="#b87333"                 
         RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
         Property=Width,Factor=.5 }"                
         RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
         Property=Height, Factor=1}">
</BoxView>

<BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" x:Name="boxview2"                
         RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression ElementName=boxview1,
         Type=RelativeToView,Property=Height,Factor=.1}" 
         RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
         ElementName=boxview1,Factor=1,Property=Width}"
         RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression   
         Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width, Factor=0.1,Constant=-10}"
         RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
         ElementName=boxview1,Property=Height,Factor=.4}">
</BoxView>

<BoxView BackgroundColor="Blue" x:Name="boxview3"
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
        ElementName=boxview2, Property=Width,Factor=.5}">
</BoxView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note: If giving `XConstraint` as `.5` I am expecting `view` on middle of screen be it Horizontal.

Output screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It's not really clear what your problem is. You want your blue boxview to be here? http://prntscr.com/mu3yln

Comment: @DenseCrab -Yes. I want blue box right of red box using `Type=RelativeToView`, that's all. When I gave X as .5 I was expecting blue box would come in middle but it wasn't. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't specify the X constraint you're looking for in Xaml, you'd have to use C#.  All elements in a RelativeLayout are positioned with respect to the entire RelativeLayout.

The Xaml you have right now specifies that boxview2's width is 0.1*RelativeLayout.Width - 10, and boxview3's X coordinate is half of that, so it will be positioned at 0.05*RelativeLayout.width - 5 from the top left, which is what you're seeing.

For RelativeLayout constraints in Xaml, you get to use exactly 1 of the X or Y of the top left of a view, or its width or height.  To achieve what you want, you need the top right of boxview2 (or boxview2.X + boxview2.Width).  You'll have to create boxview3 in the C# code behind, like:

```
reelativeLayout.Children.Add (boxview3, Constraint.RelativeToView (boxview2, (parent, view) => {
        return view.X + view.Width;
    }),
    …   // other constraints
    ));
```

Depending on your needs, you might find a different container easier to work with.